# Extracting information from a google docs table

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I am trying to extract information from a google docs table.

There maybe multiple tables in the document and the one I am trying to obtain is the one that contains the value 'mean value'

I then want to get the value from the corresponding row next column along:

Type-----------| Value

max------------| 0

min-------------|-50

mean value--|-5

other info-----|-

datum---------|0

So the result I am looking for is -5. I will then store this in google sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst Cooper's answer helps to analyse the document, for the purposes of this question, I used the following:

```
function extract(data){ 
for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        if (data[j][5] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.document') {
            try {
                var test = DocumentApp.openById(data[j][1]).getBody()
                var table1 = test.getTables()[0],table2 = test.getTables()[1]

                for (var i = 0; i < table1.getNumRows(); i++) {data[j][i+9]=table1.getCell(i, 1).getText()}

                for (var i = 1; i < table2.getNumRows(); i++) {
                    if (~table2.getCell(i, 0).getText().toLowerCase().indexOf('mean')) {
                        data[j][7] = table2.getCell(i, 1).getText();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
  return data
}
```

To put in context, I have a list of files already and the code cycles through the documents and outputs information from the first table (transpose) and 1 item from the second table.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provided a sample spreadsheet, but I think you want somrthing like this. It assumes mean value is in column A and -5 is in column B. Adjust the ranges as needed:

```
=lookup("mean value",A1:A,B1:B)
```

or:

```
=vlookup("mean value",A1:B6,2,false)
```

Comment: I should have been clear that i meant from a google docs to google spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

## A Helpful Tool for Learning More About Google Docs

This is  still a work in progress but may help you to learn a little more about Google Docs.  I display all of the children in a document in the sidebar.  In the case of tables it also help you to identify cells and edit their contents. I've had some difficulties recently providing all of the files required so [I put them all in one place](http://jimesteban.com/files/LookingInsideofGoogleDocs.txt).

Comment: that looks pretty neat. where is the htmltoBody file though

Comment: I guess I forgot it. I'll put it up tomorrow.

Comment: Okay I updated the answer with the htmltobody.html file.  Sorry about that.

Comment: It's seems that every time I've shared this I've left something out of it so here's a place where I've managed to get it altogether. Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45540289/7215091)

Comment: I will check it out. Thanks