# How to delete specific parts of a google docs using google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm would like to edit text in a google doc, specifically: 

 1) I want to delete an element of text between the first letter in the document and a predefined stop point ("//", in this case).

I've unsuccessuflly tried doing something like this:

```
    var rangeElement = DocumentApp.openById(fileID).getBody().findText("//");
          if (rangeElement.isPartial()) {
            var startOffset = rangeElement.getStartOffset([0]);
            var endOffset = rangeElement.getEndOffsetInclusive("//");
          rangeElement.getElement().asText().deleteText(startOffset,endOffset);}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: how did you define rangeElement ? Also any log in your console would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Chris - I've edited the code in the question to reflect how I defined rangeElement. Nothing is logging in my console, though I haven't defined anything to log.

Comment: getEndOffsetInclusive() does not take any variable. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element#getEndOffsetInclusive().  In order to achieve your objective, you will need to use https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findText(String)

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element, what will you have in console with the following code?    `Logger.log('The character range begins at ' + rangeElement.getStartOffset());
   Logger.log('The character range ends at ' + rangeElement.getEndOffsetInclusive());`

Answer (score 1):

## Looking inside a Google Doc

This is a tool I've used a lot and it continually changes depending upon my needs but it has been extremely useful in helping me to learn about Google Docs.  Just this evening I used it to make a document for printing envelopes. Have fun. I've always had trouble making sure that all of the files needed were provided.  So I decided to put everything including the kitchen sink in it but when I did stackoverflow echoed with an error about it being too big.  So instead [I put it on my website here](http://jimesteban.com/files/LookingInsideofGoogleDocs.txt) until I can find a better place like github.

Comment: I will take a look at this, thanks for the response!